# Paremeters on TSQL stored procedures turning the execution very slow

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

For the begining of subject, I'm using Delphi XE2 with Microsoft SQL Server.

All of the application of the my company is based on Stored Procedure, whether you want to search or manipulate data.

But **in some** search procedures I've been having the following problem: when the application triggered the procedure, turns out that the execution time is very very high. But if I trigger the same procedure, with the same paremeters of the application, inside of the SQL Management Studio, the execution time its instantly!

One way that I "resolved" was declaring the same paremeters (changing the names of course) of the procedure inside the body and assigned the same values, example:

CREATE PROCEDURE upTest( @ID int, @Name varchar(64) ) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @vID int = @ID
DECLARE @vName varchar(64) = @Name....

When I do that, the execution time when the procedure is triggered by the application its instantly as well! And gets even worse. One procedure that worked just fine yesterday, today presents this same situation.

Does anyone know why this happen? And what to do for not "recreate" the same params with same type and values?

Comment: Where's the stored procedure? Although if by "search procedures" you mean catch-all queries that tread NULL as an "ignore" value, delays are inevitable. Such queries result in bad execution plans and should be avoided.

Comment: PS there's nothing wrong with parameters or stored procedures. Show your code

Comment: Likely *Parameter Sniffing* - Canonical reading on this: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Must-read on catch-all queries and why they are so bad for performance https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: Do some research on "parameter sniffing". By declaring local variables and setting them to the parameters, you're allowing SQL Server to cache a query plan, which is good. On the other hand, your parameters might cause bad plans for some parameter values, so also do some research into `OPTION RECOMPILE` and `OPTION OPTIMIZE FOR`.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - Thanks for the reply, but the code doesn't really matter. I mean, the same procedure works just fine yesterday and today doesn't. I have been facing this problems with a lot of procedures over the past years when some customer complain about the execution time.

Comment: @EricBrandt and Alex K. Thanks very much also. I will take some look on paremter sniffing

Comment: @BrunoManguinho Eric already explained just one way it matters. Parameter sniffing problems are just one way you can get bad execution plans and they are *rare*. Catch-all queries are far more frequent. No code, no way to help. `WITH RECOMPILE` is a cure for a symptom, not a cure.

Comment: @BrunoManguinho for example, if the first time you execute a catch-all you pass a null to some parameters, the query optimizer will create an execution plan that doesn't take ignored columns into account. `RECOMPILE` will force a recompilation each time but a better solution is to simply *not* include those columns in the query. Use an ORM to create a query that contains only the required parameters. Use a view to hide the query's complexity if you need to.

Comment: @BrunoManguinho You don't get any performance boost just because you used a stored procedure. You get execution plan caching, which also works with parameterized queries. By using `WITH RECOMPILE` you lose that and thus lose the performance benefit you had by using stored procedures

Comment: Ok, thank you everybody!